# Get back code in working copy

Tags: git

I changed some files but don't use **`git add`** or **`git commit`**, it's just stay in **working copy**.

 Then I use **`git reset --hard`** to force HEAD pointer to one previous commit. Currently, the files I changed before were discarded. So, my confusion is: **Is there anyway to get the changes back?**

Comment: Next time use `git stash`: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: I'm afraid you threw away all your uncommitted changes

Comment: Did you happen to back up your system between the time you made the changes and when you ran `git reset --hard`. If not, and if you never copied the changed files somewhere else, then the answer is "No".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to get back uncommitted changes. Your best bet would be to try cached copies from editor or IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As you used `git reset --hard`, both your index and working copy were reset.

`git reset` default behavior without an option is to keep your changes but as you explicitly asked git to reset the hard way, your changes were deleted. As far as I know there is now way to undo that.

edit : I did not try it, but using `git reflog` you may be able to see your changes before the reset. If you do, you can navigate through refs using `git reset HEAD@{ref_number}` e.g. `git reset HEAD@{1}`.